# Is there a way to view your status history on Slack?

Tags: slack, data-recovery

I'd like to take a screenshot of some of my old status updates on Slack, but I can't find any kind of status history. Does such a thing exist?

**Update, July 2021:**
Not a complete history, but it looks like recent statuses are now being stored. I was unable to find a release note related to this.

[image: slack screenshot with recent status history]